# How do I move my Yeoman Angular app to a repository?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm trying to upload my Yeoman Angular app to a git repo so that other developers can work on it. How do I go about it? Meaning, which files/folders should be uploaded and which can be skipped? I don't want the other developers to run the `yo angular` command, because it creates a new app with the folder name altogether. I tried copy pasting my folder contents to a new folder, excluded the node and bower modules, then ran `npm install` and `bower  install` on this new folder. But now it fails to find `phantomjs` plugin. Is there a proper standard way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pushed it as is. There is a `.gitignore` file which handles everything. The unwanted folders are automatically ignored.